# Request-Aware Code in Google App Engine -- os.environ?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, request

In GAE, you can say [`users.get_current_user()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html#get_current_user) to get the currently logged-in user implicit to the current request. This works even if multiple requests are being processed simultaneously -- the `users` module is somehow aware of which request the `get_current_user` function is being called on behalf of. I took a look into the code of the module in the development server, and it seems to be using `os.environ` to get the user email and other values associated to the current request.

Does this mean that every request gets an independent `os.environ` object?

I need to implement a service similar to `users.get_current_user()` that would return different values depending on the request being handled by the calling code. Assuming `os.environ` is the way to go, how do I know which variable names are already being used (or reserved) by GAE?

Also, is there a way to add a hook (or event handler) that gets called before every request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html) say,

> A Python web app interacts with the
>   App Engine web server using the CGI
>   protocol.

This basically means exactly one request is being served at one time within any given process (although, differently from real CGI, one process can be serially reused for multiple requests, one after the other, if it defines `main` functions in the various modules to which `app.yaml` dispatches).  See also [this page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Requests_and_CGI), and [this one](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/env.html) for documentation of the environment variables CGI defines and uses.

The hooks App Engine defines are around calls at the RPC layer, not the HTTP requests.  To intercept each request before it gets served, you could use `app.yaml` to redirect all requests to a single `.py` file and perform your interception in that file's `main` function before redirecting (or, you could call your hook at the start of the `main` in every module you're using `app.yaml` to dispatch to).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It's cleared up some confusion on my end. I'm actually already redirecting all (non-static) requests to a single .py file. I could add code to my main, but I'd like to be notified of the actual Request objects, so I'm going to override the 'initialize' method in a class that inherits from RequestHandler, then inherit from that class instead of directly from RequestHandler.